# Unmatched close brace/bracket

Tags: bash, curl, syntax

I'm trying to execute an script in bash, but throw me this error,

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 24:
UTC","user_id":"01234"}}
```

i tried removing the braces but does not work, this is the line,

```
response=$(curl  -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cursus_user":{"begin_at":"'${start}'","cursus_id":"'${cursus_id}'","end_at":"'${end}'","user_id":"'${user}'"}}' "https://xxxxxx/xxxxxx.com")
```

Anyone know where is the issue?, i'm stuck, thanks in advance.

[ UPDATE ]

Really i can't see the error :(

```
'
{
    "cursus_user":
    {
        "begin_at":     "'${start}'",
        "cursus_id":    "'${cursus_id}'",
        "end_at":       "'${end}'",
        "user_id":      "'${user}'"
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Looks like the error is happening at position 24, which is the curly bracket after `Authorization: Bearer ${` or what is the value of ${bearer_token}

Comment: Well, the error was in the date of begin and end, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a formatted comment.

Two tips:

- use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to generate JSON -- it will get all the quoting correct for you
- use arrays for readability (I dislike scrolling horizontally)

```bash
data=$(
    jq  --null-input \
        --compact-output \
        --arg begin_at  "$start" \
        --arg cursus_id "$cursus_id" \
        --arg end_at    "$end" \
        --arg user_id   "$user" \
        '{cursus_user: $ARGS.named}'
)

curl_opts=(
    -X POST
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}"
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d "$data"
)

response=$(curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "https://xxxxxx/xxxxxx.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several unquoted variables in the `curl` command.  It even provides the corrected code:

```
response=$(curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${bearer_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cursus_user":{"begin_at":"'"${start}"'","cursus_id":"'"${cursus_id}"'","end_at":"'"${end}"'","user_id":"'"${user}"'"}}' "https://xxxxxx/xxxxxx.com")
```

Using [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) often saves a lot of time when working with shell code.

Comment: lol, this tool totally saved my day :D

Answer (score 0):

add additional double quotes; say., `"'"${start}"'"` instead of `"'${start}'"`

```
{
    "cursus_user":
    {
        "begin_at":     "'"${start}"'",
        "cursus_id":    "'"${cursus_id}"'",
        "end_at":       "'"${end}"'",
        "user_id":      "'"${user}"'"
    }
}
```